# Mongoose creates incomplete documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So, I am trying to seed the database with some sample data that I have in JSON format. Here is the function:

```
    request(options, (err, res, body) => {
                if (!err && body) {
                    var classId;
                    body.forEach((element, i) => {
                        Student.create(element, (err, success) => {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log("This is a error", err)
                            } else if (i % 4 === 0) {
                                console.log(`This is the division for ${i}`, i % 4)
                                let testClass = new Class();
                                console.log(testClass)
                                testClass.name = `Class ${i}`;
                                testClass.students.push(success._id);
                                testClass.save((err, successClass) => {
                                    console.log("This is the class created", successClass)
                                    classId = successClass._id;
                                    console.log("This is a the class id", classId)
                                    User.findOne({ email: 'admin@example.com' }, (err, foundUser) => {
                                        foundUser.classId.push(successClass._id);
                                    })
                                })
                            } else {
                                console.log(classId)
                                Class.findById(classId, (err, foundClass) => {
                                    foundClass.students.push(success._id);
                                    foundClass.save();

                                })
                            }
                        })
                    })
                }
            });
```

I am facing two different problems with this code, 1. Mongoose creates a few incomplete documents. 2. ClassId variable can't store the value.

For second problem, I'll ask a different question.

The logic here is that I have a sample of 20 students, and I want to create 5 groups with 4 students each.

Here is what I get in my console

```
This is the division for 0 0
{ _id: 595b028dc7000c18b71d14b5,
  activeStaus: true,
  students: [],
  dateCreated: 2017-07-04T02:50:47.296Z,
  teachers: [] }
undefined
undefined
This is the division for 4 0
{ _id: 595b028dc7000c18b71d14b6,
  activeStaus: true,
  students: [],
  dateCreated: 2017-07-04T02:50:47.296Z,
  teachers: [] }
This is the division for 8 0
{ _id: 595b028dc7000c18b71d14b7,
  activeStaus: true,
  students: [],
  dateCreated: 2017-07-04T02:50:47.296Z,
  teachers: [] }
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
This is the division for 16 0
{ _id: 595b028dc7000c18b71d14b8,
  activeStaus: true,
  students: [],
  dateCreated: 2017-07-04T02:50:47.296Z,
  teachers: [] }
This is the division for 12 0
{ _id: 595b028dc7000c18b71d14b9,
  activeStaus: true,
  students: [],
  dateCreated: 2017-07-04T02:50:47.296Z,
  teachers: [] }
undefined
undefined
undefined
This is the class created { __v: 0,
  name: 'Class 4',
  _id: 595b028dc7000c18b71d14b6,
  activeStaus: true,
  students: [ 595b028dc7000c18b71d14a5 ],
  dateCreated: 2017-07-04T02:50:47.296Z,
  teachers: [] }
This is a the class id 595b028dc7000c18b71d14b6
This is the class created { __v: 0,
  name: 'Class 8',
  _id: 595b028dc7000c18b71d14b7,
  activeStaus: true,
  students: [ 595b028dc7000c18b71d14a9 ],
  dateCreated: 2017-07-04T02:50:47.296Z,
  teachers: [] }
This is a the class id 595b028dc7000c18b71d14b7
This is the class created { __v: 0,
  name: 'Class 0',
  _id: 595b028dc7000c18b71d14b5,
  activeStaus: true,
  students: [ 595b028dc7000c18b71d14a1 ],
  dateCreated: 2017-07-04T02:50:47.296Z,
  teachers: [] }
This is a the class id 595b028dc7000c18b71d14b5
```

As you can see in the logs that the first few documents don't have the name property and they have empty students array.

I think it has something to do the iteration, because in my head the values of `i` would be 0,1,2,3,4...19 in that order, even if that's not the case, I still can't understand the incomplete documents.

**Edit: Here are the classSchema and studentSchema**

**Student Schema**

```
var StudentSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    role: String,
    added: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    email: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true
    },
    password: String,
    provider: String,
    pin: String,
    school: String,
    salt: String,
    schoolId:  mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    classId:  mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    teacherId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    className: String,
    activeStaus:{type:Boolean,default:true},
    grade: String,
    grade_id: Number,
    teacheName: String,
    teacherNumber: String,
    teacherEmail: String,
    courseName: String,
    courseNumber: String,
    courseId: Number,
    period: Number,
    gender: String,
    number: Number,
    realisticInterests: Number,
    investigativeInterests: Number,
    artisticInterests: Number,
    socialInterests: Number,
    entrepreneurialInterests: Number,
    conventionalInterests: Number,
    careerDecidedness: Number,
    neuroticism: Number,
    extraversion: Number,
    opennessToExperience: Number,
    conscientiousness: Number,
    agreeableness: Number,
    activeLearner: Number,
    reflectiveLearner: Number,
    theoreticalLearner: Number,
    progmaticLearner: Number,
    socialDesirability: Number
});
```

**Class Schema**

```
var classSchema = new Schema({
  schoolId:  mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  teachers:Array,
  dateCreated:{type:Date,default:Date.now()},
  name : String,
  students:[{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'User'}],
  activeStaus:{type:Boolean,default:true}
});
```

**Sample Data**

I can't post the complete data since it would overpopulate this thread, and I have checked the data thoroughly, it isn't any required property. Here is a sample

```
  {
    "Sr. No.": 1,
    "school_name": "Franklin High School",
    "school_number": 1001,
    "school_id": "",
    "grade": 11,
    "grade_id": "",
    "teacher_name": "Merideth Merrill",
    "teacher_number": 539224,
    "teacher_id": "",
    "teacher_email": "",
    "course_name": "Physics 1",
    "course_number": 101,
    "course_id": "",
    "period": 1,
    "student_name": "Agnes Walters",
    "student_gender": "",
    "student_number": "",
    "student_id": 1000,
    "student_pin": "",
    "student_email": "",
    "realistic_interests": 1.55,
    "investigative_interests": 4.55,
    "artistic_interests": 4.92,
    "social_interests": 4.96,
    "entrepreneurial_interests": 1.98,
    "conventional_interests": 4.5,
    "career_decidedness": 4.66,
    "neuroticism": 2.49,
    "extraversion": 1.98,
    "openness_to_experience": 1.92,
    "conscientiousness": 2.14,
    "agreeableness": 0.71,
    "active_learner": 4.86,
    "reflective_learner": 4.08,
    "theoretical_learner": 4.99,
    "progmatic_learner": 3.18,
    "social_desirability": 0.92
  },
```

Comment: where did you set the value to `var classId;`

Comment: In the `else if` block see `classId = successClass._id`

Comment: Show the relevant schema for `Class`, `Student` and `User`. Also the content of `body` which is being passed in. As noted `classId` is undefined since these are "async" methods, and the condition gets reached before it can be possibly set. As for the others, it's likely the information provided does not match the defined schema, and therefore gets rejected. So show the schema in your question along with the data being supplied so we can correct you.

Comment: @NeilLunn Hey, I've updated my question.